# How do I get a count of events each day with SQL?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-ce

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Timestamp          Event   User
================   =====   =====
1/1/2010 1:00 PM   100     John
1/1/2010 1:00 PM   103     Mark
1/2/2010 2:00 PM   100     John
1/2/2010 2:05 PM   100     Bill
1/2/2010 2:10 PM   103     Frank
```

I want to write a query that shows the events for each day and a count for those events. Something like:

```
Date       Event   EventCount
========   =====   ==========
1/1/2010   100     1
1/1/2010   103     1
1/2/2010   100     2
1/2/2010   103     1
```

The database is SQL Server Compact, so it doesn't support all the features of the full SQL Server. The query I have written so far is

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Timestamp), 0) as Date, Event, Count(Event) as EventCount
FROM Log
GROUP BY Timestamp, Event
```

This almost works, but EventCount is always 1. How can I get SQL Server to return the correct counts? All fields are mandatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your goup by to

```
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Timestamp), 0), Event
```